# Rails 4 --> Paperclip adding "%3F1417409694" to image file name -- causing failure to load resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip

I have installed paperclip into my Rails 4 application. I mostly followed the tutorial listed below to do so.

- [Paperclip](http://robmclarty.com/blog/how-to-install-image-magick-and-setup-paperclip)

The gist of this issue (and what I believe is the main source of the problem) is summarized at the bottom of this post under **Final Thoughts**

However, if you are so inclined to see everything I have included. This is what I have done to attach images using Paperclip

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'paperclip', github: 'thoughtbot/paperclip'
```

**Product.rb** (Model)

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :small => "150x150>" },  
  :url => "/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",  
  :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"  


do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image

end
```

**Migration**

```
class AddAttachmentImageToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :products do |t|
      t.attachment :image
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :products, :image
  end
end
```

**products/index.html.erb** (Products table)

```
<%- model_class = Product -%>
<div class="page-header">
  <h1><%=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human.pluralize.titleize %></h1>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:image) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:id) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:name) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:price) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:category) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:created_at) %></th>
      <th><%=t '.actions', :default => t("helpers.actions") %></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <tr>
        <td> <%= image_tag product.image.url(:small) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to product.id, product_path(product) %></td>
        <td><%= product.name %></td>
        <td><%= product.price %></td>
...
.....
```

**_form.html.erb** (form used for creation of new products)

```
<%= form_for @product, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <% if @product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_expl" class="panel panel-danger">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
        <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <%= error_span(@product[:name]) %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
</div>
...
.....
```

**Observations**

Here is a snippet of the errors I recieve in the terminal ..

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/products/4/small/pflogo.png%3F1417408937"):
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagg
```

I am very unsure of why it adds the %3F1417408937 to the end of my image file name?

The image file is truly located at `public/assets/products/pflogo.png`

So, my guess is that the `:url` and :`path` I have set in the model is incorrect in some way.

- On my products page (`localhst:3000/products`) there is a blank placeholder for an image. The common 'broken image' thumbnail. When I inspect the element via chrome developer tools I see the following

  Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionbootstrap.js?body=1:3 (anonymous         function)jquery.js?body=1:3120 firejquery.js?body=1:3232 self.fireWithjquery.js?body=1:3444 jQuery.extend.readyjquery.js?body=1:3475 completed

  products:115 GET ....://localhost:3000/assets/products/4/small/pflogo.png%3F1417409694 404 (Not Found)
  products:127 GET ....://localhost:3000/images/small/missing.png 404 (Not Found)
  products:223 GET ....://localhost:3000/assets/products/17/small/pflogo.png%3F1417340013 404 (Not Found)

**Final Thoughts**

So, again we see that Paperclip is adding `%3F1417409694` to my image file name. When I edit this out using Inspect Element, the correct result is produced and I am able to see the image on the Products page.

Comment: Given that `%3F1417409694` url-decodes to `?1417409694` it almost looks like something's trying to add an ID or some kind of cache-buster to the URL... Could you tell us why you want to use the absolute latest Paperclip from Github? Most people will want a more stable version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change the gem 'paperclip', github: 'thoughtbot/paperclip' in your gem file to

gem "paperclip"

and bundle again add the image it will work

Comment: Yup, looks like [this issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1706).